# Cordova: How to lock app orientation at boot to landscape and not landscape-reverse?

Tags: cordova, orientation, screen-orientation

I'm building a tilt-based game and want to lock the orientation to 1 particular landscape orientation (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight on iOS). However, if you set the cordova Orientation preference to `landscape`, it can still rotate 180 degrees to either landscape mode, which isn't acceptable for me. Is this a shortcoming of cordova? I need this, and it's trivial to do natively, so seems like there ought be an easy way to do it.

I'm aware of [cordova-plugin-screen-orientation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation/), but it only does stuff once your javascript has started running, which is too late for your splash screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution: cordova allows you to edit native attributes through your config.xml file. I feel this ought to be supported natively by cordova itself, but this will work:

```
<platform name="android">
    <edit-config 
                 file="AndroidManifest.xml"
                 target="/manifest/application/activity[@android:name='MainActivity']"
                 mode="merge"
                 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <activity android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>
    </edit-config>
</platform>
```

Comment: This crashes my build :/

Answer (score 5):

Currently I am finding the answer for Android and the accepted answer cannot be used now.
In Cordova root folder config.xml add:

```
<platform name="android">
        <preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
</platform>
```

Then the app will be landscaped.

Comment: To me this should be the correct answer, the accepted answer no longer works and I don't see a reason to use the screen-orientation plugin. +1

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this using android, I got it to work (on my phone at least) by adding the below to my config.xml (inside the Widget element)

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Please select landscape and then create build

[image]

Comment: I don't know what tool you're using. Setting it to landscape is what I've already done in the config.xml.

Comment: Please use cordova-plugin-screen-orientation  plugin for screen lock :
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation/

Please first install plugin then put below code in your deviceready method locate from app js file


// set to either landscape
screen.orientation.lock('landscape');

// allow user rotate
screen.orientation.unlock();

Comment: Did you read my question? I already said I've tried that plugin, and it only works after your app has booted, which is too late to affect the splash screen.